# Web Scraping a web page that uses JavaScript to Render content

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, flutter, dart

I am building an app using flutter/dart, that requires getting content from a web site. However, i am now realizing that this web site uses JavaScript to render the information that it shows.

My question is, is there any way to scrape this JavaScript data using Dart?

I've already used HTML and HTTP dependencies to get and parse the simple html data, it's just an issue of getting that Javascript rendered data.

Comment: This has been asked several times in many different ways. The answer is always the same. To scrape a webpage that renders content with javascript you need to use a browser engine. You can use phantomjs, selenium, webdriver, or a number of other tools. I don't know that any of these have a Flutter adapter.

Comment: What's the purpose of scraping a web page?

Comment: Thank you all. I am a fairly new developer and this is one of my first bigger solo projects so i apologize for re-asking the question.